# React and JS Web Component - onChange Event Gets Lost when Cloning HTML from Template to Component Output

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, web-component, cloning

I have a React app and I want to use a reusable JS web component that is supposed to output a `<dialog>` with content cloned from HTML inserted into the `<custom-tag>` of same JS component.

The HTML I want to clone has an `<input type="file">` with an `onChange' event.

Once the JS component renders the `<dialog>` with the cloned HTML the `onChange` event gets lost and nothing happens as expected.

I'm looking for a way **to NOT loose** any of the events on any inputs and/or buttons passed on to the JS component.

I will provide code samples and a link to a GitHub repo.

https://github.com/ChidoYo/dialog-component.git

### App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './webComponent/dialog_component'

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      "dialog-component": DialogComponentProps;
    }
  }
}

interface DialogComponentProps
  extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<
    React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>,
    HTMLElement
  > {
  trigger: string;
  target: string;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>¡Hola!</h1>

      <div className='sample'>
        <p>Plain File Input</p>
        Upload
        <input
          type="file"
          id="plain"
          className='input-file'
          onChange={() => console.log('Outside Dialog')}
          accept="image/jpeg, image/png"
        />
      </div>

      <button className="btn-open" id="openDialog">Open Modal</button>

      <dialog-component id="dialogSample" trigger="openDialog" target="myDialog">
        <div>
          <p>File Upload in Dialog</p>
          <label htmlFor="outter-one" className='input-label'>
            Upload Picture
            <input
              type="file"
              id="outter-one"
              className='input-file'
              accept="image/jpeg, image/png"
              onChange={() => console.log('Inside Component')}
            />
          </label>          
        </div>
      </dialog-component>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### JS Web Component

```
class DialogComponent extends HTMLElement {

  connectedCallback() {

    const id = this.getAttribute('id')
    const trigger = this.getAttribute('trigger')
    const target = this.getAttribute('target')

    let dialogChildren = document.getElementById(id).firstChild.cloneNode(true)
    dialogChildren = dialogChildren.innerHTML

    console.log('dialogChildren', dialogChildren);

    const dialogContent = `
      <dialog id="${target}">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <div class="text-content">
          ${dialogChildren}
        </div>
        <button class="btn-close" close-dialog autofocus>Close Modal</button>
      </dialog>
    `

    this.innerHTML = dialogContent

    // Open Dialog
    const openButton = document.getElementById(trigger)
    const closeButton = this.querySelector('[close-dialog]')
    const dialog = this.querySelector(`#${target}`)

    openButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault()      
      dialog.showModal()
    })

    closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => dialog.close())
  }
}

customElements.define('dialog-component', DialogComponent)
```

Comment: This JS Web Component is directly manipulating the DOM, which is not a good idea in a React app.  Though it *could* work....why would you want to?  Why not turn the JS Web Component into a proper React component?

Comment: @GregFenton I was expecting a comment like this.  If it's possible to do please let me know.  Let me deal with the component that is already in use.

Comment: The problem will end up being that we don't know the rest of your React project that could be doing all sorts of things to the DOM.  Injecting arbitrary items to the DOM is super hard to nail down misbehaviours.  The HTML doesn't seem to be doing anything too crazy, so why not simply convert it to be a proper React component?

Comment: Your suggestion is valid, but you must understand that I'm dealing with work requirements. ‍♂️

Comment: _"Because React implements its own synthetic event system, it cannot listen for DOM events coming from Custom Elements without the use of a workaround"_ See https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/

Comment: The work requirement is to build a bridge of glass?  If you take an informed engineering position back to the business, they reject it?  Engineers should have the opportunity to inform the business in terms of technical decisions and/or risks, right?

Comment: I am curious why you are cloning `dialogChildren` instead of using `<slot></slot>`

Comment: @Intervalia I will explore using `<slot>`.  I am currently building a React component but I still would like to figure out a way to accomplish what I first set out to do.  I will make sure to return here when I do.   Question for you, I don't want the HTML for my `<dialog>` in the shadowDOM because I'm still relying on global css.  Can I still use the `<slot>` putting my content in the shadowDOM?

Comment: If you use `<slot>` for the content of the dialog then all of the HTML that goes into the `<slot>` is affected by global CSS and *almost* can not be affected by shadowDOM CSS (see this page for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted). The only thing that is controlled by shadowDOM css is the HTML you place directly into the shadowDOM.